# Say my input file is table delimited, how do i get the class name and the executable time using AWK

Tags: shell, awk

Say my input file is table delimited, how can get the class name and the executable time?

```
 - class Apple.java executed by user ABC34 executable time 980.9 ms
 - class ABC.java executed by user ABC34  executable time is in sec 45.9 ss
 - class TAS.java executed by user ABC34  executable time 75.9 ms
 - class GW.java executed by user ABC34  executable time is in sec 0.9 ss
 - class MYClass.java executed by user ABC34  executable time  is in sec 7.9 ss
 - class Times.java executed by user ABC34  executable time  is in sec 9.9 ss
 - class Sunday.java executed by user ABC34  executable time  is in sec 85.9 ss
 - class Week.java executed by user ABC34  executable time  is in sec 1000.9 ss
```

I want the out put like this

```
 - Apple.java 980.9 ms
 - ABC.java  45.9 ss
 - TAS.java  75.9 ms
 - GW.java  0.9 ss
 - MYClass.java 7.9 ss
 - Times.java  9.9 ss
 - Sunday.java 85.9 ss
 - Week.java  1000.9 ss
```

please see my code. i can't able to get out put

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=$1
SEARCH=$2

echo $SEARCH

if [ -f $LOGFILE ];
then

awk '/ABC34 / && /is in sec/ {print $2, $13, $14;}' $LOGFILE>Output.txt
awk '/ABC34 / {print $2, $8, $9;}' $LOGFILE>Output.csv

else
echo "No File Found"
fi
```

But when i check my Output.txt is empty. Many Thanks.

Comment: Is there ` - ` (space hyphen space) in the beginning of each line? Also, note that you should `>>` instead of `>` so that it appends content.

Comment: yes its a log file. its start with '-'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` its a one-liner:

```
awk '{print $1,$3,$(NF-1),$NF}' your.file
```

`NF` contains the number of fields in a line. So the command prints the 1., the 3. the next to last and the last field.

Output:

```
- Apple.java 980.9 ms
- ABC.java 45.9 ss
- TAS.java 75.9 ms
- GW.java 0.9 ss
- MYClass.java 7.9 ss
- Times.java 9.9 ss
- Sunday.java 85.9 ss
- Week.java 1000.9 ss
```

Answer (score 1):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r 's/.*class\s(\S+)\s.*(\s[0-9.]+\s[ms][ms])$/- \1\2/' file
```

---

```
$ cat file
- class Apple.java executed by user ABC34 executable time 980.9 ms
- class ABC.java executed by user ABC34  executable time is in sec 45.9 ss
- class TAS.java executed by user ABC34  executable time 75.9 ms
- class GW.java executed by user ABC34  executable time is in sec 0.9 ss
- class MYClass.java executed by user ABC34  executable time  is in sec 7.9 ss
- class Times.java executed by user ABC34  executable time  is in sec 9.9 ss
- class Sunday.java executed by user ABC34  executable time  is in sec 85.9 ss
- class Week.java executed by user ABC34  executable time  is in sec 1000.9 ss

$ sed -r 's/.*class\s(\S+)\s.*(\s[0-9.]+\s[ms][ms])$/- \1\2/' file
- Apple.java 980.9 ms
- ABC.java 45.9 ss
- TAS.java 75.9 ms
- GW.java 0.9 ss
- MYClass.java 7.9 ss
- Times.java 9.9 ss
- Sunday.java 85.9 ss
- Week.java 1000.9 ss
```